# Change all url titles - Remove illegal characters

Tags: url-title

I've just noticed that a client has created a large number of entries with illegal characters in the url titles. This is causing all osrts of problems with entries displaying incorrectly.

Is there a quick and dirty way to mass change all of the entry titles to remove the illegal characters (commas, periods, apostrophe's etc)?

Comment: Why is EE even allowing these characters in URL titles in the first place? We recently had an issue related to odd characters in the url title also and seems to me like EE should be stripping these out to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the update query directly to replace these special characters like:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_titles set url_title = REPLACE(url_title, '+', ' ') WHERE channel_id=1 AND status='open' AND site_id=1
```

The above sql will replace + character with space of all the entries having channel_id as 1 and status as 'open'.

You need to run the query for each character which you would like to remove/replace.

I would suggest you take a backup to avoid any accident.

I hope it would help you.